# Android Toast text is askew (align to top)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-toast

Do you have any ide why my Toast has askew test, aligned to top?
[Here is preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s53oo.png)

I only use 
`Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), place.placeName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`
 on item click in recycler view;

Comment: try not using the views context and just use the activities context

Comment: Not working. I replaced v.getContext() with context from constructor and still the same

Comment: constructor from where, post more code

Comment: check styles, there may override a style for it

Comment: tyczj - I tried to make Toast in MainActivity and the same.
SorryForMyEnglish - which styles are resposible for default Toast apperance?

Comment: style of your application

Comment: Yes, value `android:fitsSystemWindows` is responsible for this. Thanks for suggestion. Workaround is replace `v.getContext()` with `v.getContext().getApplicationContext()`